# Pinball-Game / JavaScript: How can i implement the collision detection?

Tags: javascript, python, html, game-development

I need to develop a small single page 2D game for university. The backend REST API with Python, the frontend with HTML/CSS, the logic with JavaScript. We are supposed to develop the animations ourselves and not take them from canvas objects for example.

I'm currently trying a pinball game and have built the basic framework with CSS. Only I imagined the collision detection to be much easier than it probably is.

Here's what the playfield looks like at the moment:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITLdF.png)

The JavaScript logic so that the ball stays in the playfield is quite simple:

```
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');
var playArea = document.getElementById('play-area');
var ballRadius = 10;
var playAreaWidth = playArea.offsetWidth; // 600
var playAreaHeight = playArea.offsetHeight; // 820
var ballX = playAreaWidth / 2; // Startposition des Balls in der Mitte des Spielfelds
var ballY = playAreaHeight / 2; // X = 300, Y = 410
var ballSpeedX = 3; // Geschwindigkeit des Balls in horizontaler Richtung
var ballSpeedY = 3; // Geschwindigkeit des Balls in vertikaler Richtung

function updateBallPosition() {
    // Aktualisiere die Position des Balls basierend auf der aktuellen Geschwindigkeit
    ballX += ballSpeedX;
    ballY += ballSpeedY;

    if (ballX + ballRadius > playAreaWidth || ballX - ballRadius < 0) {
      ballSpeedX *= -1; // Richtungswechsel in der horizontalen Richtung
    }

    if (ballY + ballRadius > playAreaHeight || ballY - ballRadius < 0) {
      ballSpeedY *= -1; // Richtungswechsel in der vertikalen Richtung
    }

    // Setze die neue Position des Balls
    ball.style.left = ballX + 'px';
    ball.style.top = ballY + 'px';
}

// Aktualisiere die Position des Balls alle 16 Millisekunden (ca. 60 Frames pro Sekunde)
setInterval(updateBallPosition, 16);
```

But how to implement it so that the ball bounces off the obstacles and boards properly, so that a change of direction occurs, I haven't really understood yet. I was thinking that with js you can quite easily getten the frame of the css objects, and thus the ball bounces and changes direction when touching the obstacles and bands of the field. Would anyone have any ideas or experience on how to approach collision detection here?
Greetings and thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You probably need the position of the point when touching the obstacle and the one before that, so that you can know the direction from where the ball came. Then with the edge of the object, assuming it is a straight line, you could calculate the degree by which the ball has to bounce off the object. But maybe there are libraries, which can do those calculations.

Comment: If you want a *realistic* pinball game, where the ball can gain speed if you push the flippers harder, and when gravity causes the ball to slow down and fall again, and bounce off all the walls, then you really need a physics library. I find matter.js the easiest to work with. If you want to calculate collision between line and circle yourself you'll have to google for the math formula, or use a library that does only that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-circle-collision

Comment: How complex are the shapes that the ball will be encountering? Are they simple rectangles or circles or could they be any random shape?

Comment: @AHaworth, there is literately a picture attached to the question.

Comment: @Bennet, This is too broad of a question for SO. Consider using a physics library like Kokodoko says, then come back if you are stuck somewhere :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir yes I saw the picture but that didn't show the sort of 'maze' of pins and clusters of pins in different shapes that I would have expected on a pinball machine.

Comment: See [ask]. It's unspecific. Anyway, I recommend to use a Physics engine such as [Box2d.js](https://github.com/kripken/box2d.js/), [matter.js](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js), etc.